# Why don't all the readline shortcuts work in psql (or IRB, or the Rails console)?

Tags: readline, irb, postgresql

In bash and zsh, you can use handy readline shortcuts like [these](http://www.bigsmoke.us/readline/shortcuts) to navigate between words, delete from the middle of the line, etc.

However, only a couple of these (Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E and a couple of others) work in psql, IRB, and the Rails console and probably others.

Why is this, and how hard would it be to fix it? It sure would be handy to be able to quickly navigate between words in a long SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Are your copies of psql &c built with readline?

From the sound of it, yours might be built with an alternate editing library like [libedit](http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/).  To get all the features of [readline](http://www.gnu.org/s/readline/), build them using it.

Comment: Hmmm... good question. I'm pretty sure I just installed psql with Homebrew. How do I find out if it's built with readline or libedit?

Comment: That I don't know, `--version` doesn't go into specifics.  From [the homebrew page](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/postgresql.rb), it depends on readline, but doesn't obviously use it during configuration.